# How to handle listings, fancyvrb, newfloat and caption?

Tags: floats, listings, captions, fancyvrb

I am planning a "small thesis" for university which will need to display lots of code (C, C++, gnuplot, LaTeX, ...) - thus I spent this evening reading about `listings` and `fancyvrb`. The latter I've already been using together with the `newfloat`- and `caption`-package. The former seems very appealing and handy (linebreaking, indexing, caption without floating body...) during my first experiments.

All the four packages grant compability with each other, yet I am confused as for instance both, `caption` *and* `listings`, provide caption-functionality, or both, `newfloat` and `listings`, could be used to create a "Table of Listings", etc...

I'm afraid I have no specific question... I'm rather asking for hints or advice on how to use these four packages together. For example: Should I assign the float/caption-management to `newfloat` and `caption` only? Which of the code-packages should "do the main part of the job"? Is it possible to define independent code-environments with their individual "lists of listings"? Is there a convenient way to generate different styles of inline listings? Etc.

I would be glad if you could start me off and steer me in a promising direction so that I can - if necessesary - ask more precise questions in the course of setting everything up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question, it seems that you need the ability to write code in several languages, provide captions for the listings and to create a "List of listings". In this case, the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package offers you everything you need.

1. `\lstlistoflistings` allow you to create the list of all captioned listings. With not much effort, you can even have independent list for each type of language; see the example code below in which environments were defined for LaTeX, C++ and Gnuplot listings and each one will have its own counter and List of listings.
2. It offers a number of predefined languages (among them, the ones you mentioned C, C++, Gnuplot, LaTeX) and you can further customize them.
3. It provides its own caption mechanism, but if you use the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package to customize your captions, you can easily override the listings settings, if required.
4. By default, long listings don't float and will admit page breaks. Using the `float` key, your listing will be treated like a floating object (which could be handy under some circumstances); notice, however, that floating objects don't admit page breaks.

The `caption` package will allow you to customize the look and feel of your captions. The package does cooperate with `listings`.

You would only use `newfloat` in case you required to use a new type of floating object, which doesn't seem necessary for your code snippets; as I mentioned, before, you can easily turn a `lstlisting` environment into a floating object (if required) without any new package

In short, I'd say (judging by your question), that `listings` is the way to go and you can eventually use `caption` if you want to change the feel and look of your captions.

A simple example showing how quickly you can set customized environments for your listings using the `listings` package; I defined two environments, one for C++ code and the other one for LaTeX.

I used the `caption` package to change the default font used for the label of the captions and the separator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}

% some colors for the listings
\colorlet{cppkeyword}{teal}
\colorlet{latexkeyword}{green!50!black}
\colorlet{gnuplotkeyword}{magenta!60!black}
\colorlet{gnuplotcomment}{teal}
\colorlet{symb}{red!50!black}
\colorlet{comm}{brown}

% for captions: boldfaced labels, separator=period
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{labelfont=bf,labelsep=period}

% style for c++ listings
\lstdefinestyle{cpp}{%
  language=C++,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{cppkeyword},
  literate=%
    {\{}{\textcolor{symb}{\{}}1
    {\}}{\textcolor{symb}{\}}}1
    {(}{\textcolor{symb}{(}}1
    {)}{\textcolor{symb}{)}}1
    {;}{\textcolor{symb}{;}}1
}

% style for LaTeX listings
\lstdefinestyle{latex}{%
  language=[LaTeX]{TeX},
  texcsstyle=*\bfseries\color{latexkeyword}, 
  literate=%
    {\{}{\textcolor{symb}{\{}}1
    {\}}{\textcolor{symb}{\}}}1
    {(}{\textcolor{symb}{(}}1
    {)}{\textcolor{symb}{)}}1
    {\%}{\textcolor{comm}{\%}}1
}

% style for Gnuplot listings
\lstdefinestyle{gnuplot}{%
  language=Gnuplot,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{gnuplotkeyword},
  commentstyle={\itshape\color{gnuplotcomment}},
  literate=%
    {"}{\textcolor{symb}{"}}1
}

% Common style for all listings
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  tabsize=3
}

% We tweak the default settings for C++ listings
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{\texttt{C++} listings}

\lstnewenvironment{cpp}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand\lstlistingname{\texttt{C++} listing}
  \lstset{style=cpp,#1}}{}

% Counters for LaTeX and Gnuplot listings and an auxiliary counter
\newcounter{latexlst}
\newcounter{gnuplotlst}
\newcounter{tmp}

\makeatletter
% Environment for LaTeX listings; extension for auxiliar file: lll
\lstnewenvironment{latex}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand\lstlistingname{\LaTeX\ listing}
  \setcounter{tmp}{\value{lstlisting}}
  \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{latexlst}}
  \lstset{style=latex,nolol,#1}
}{%
  \refstepcounter{latexlst}
  \addcontentsline{lll}{lstlisting}{\protect\numberline{\thelstlisting}\lst@@caption}%
  \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{tmp}}
}

% Settings for the List of LaTeX listings
\newcommand\lstlistoflatexlistings{%
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{\LaTeX\ listings}
  \let\contentsname\lstlistlistingname
  \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lll}}%
  \tableofcontents
  \egroup%
}

% Environment for Gnuplot listings; extension for auxiliar file: lgl
\lstnewenvironment{gnuplot}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand\lstlistingname{\texttt{Gnuplot} listing}
  \setcounter{tmp}{\value{lstlisting}}
  \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{gnuplotlst}}
  \lstset{style=gnuplot,nolol,#1}
}{%
  \refstepcounter{gnuplotlst}
  \addcontentsline{lgl}{lstlisting}{\protect\numberline{\thelstlisting}\lst@@caption}%
  \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{tmp}}
}

% Settings for the List of Gnuplot listings
\newcommand\lstlistofgnuplotlistings{%
  \bgroup
  \renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{\texttt{Gnuplot} listings}
  \let\contentsname\lstlistlistingname
  \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lgl}}%
  \tableofcontents
  \egroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings
\lstlistoflatexlistings
\lstlistofgnuplotlistings

\begin{cpp}[caption={test code for \texttt{C++}},label={lst:c++}]
long some_function();
int other_function(); 

int calling_function()
{
        long test1;
        int test2;
}
\end{cpp}

\begin{latex}[caption={test code for \LaTeX},label={lst:latex}]
\newcommand\mycom[1]{%
    \fbox{#1}%
}
\end{latex}

\begin{gnuplot}[caption={test code for \texttt{Gnuplot}},label={lst:gnuplot}]
# 1st step
set term "table"
set output "temp.dat"
splot ....
\end{gnuplot}

\LaTeX code: \lstinline[style=latex]{\documentclass}\par
\texttt{Gnuplot} code: \lstinline[style=gnuplot]{set output "temp.dat"}\par
\texttt{C++} code: \lstinline[style=cpp]{int calling_function()}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the ample response. The features you mentioned are the ones I already stumbled over, but listed and demonstrated very neatly! By now `listings` indeed seems to cover everything I will need. Do the `lstdefinestyle`- and `lstnewenvironment`-commands etc. provide the means to, for instance, create two independent "lists of listings" (which would be possible using the `newfloat`-package, I guess)? If you could maybe imply this in your answer, please? I then could edit into the introducing question, as well.

Comment: Also, apart from `lstMakeShortInline`, can I define several inline-styles via `listings` (or will LaTeX-newcommands suffice there)?

Comment: @LCsa it's not convenient to use `newfloat` since the new environments would be floating objects, not admitting page breaks. In any case, it's not necessary to use it; you can define your independent lists using some appropriate definitions (I've added some code to my answer showing three independent lists without any additional packages).

Comment: @LCsa yes, `lstMakeShortInline` will allow you to define several in-line styles; you can also use `\lstinline[style=<style>]{<code>}` as I did in my updated answer.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!
One more thing: _If_ I wanted to use floating objects as well, would you still use the counters you presented (by adding the `float`-option to the `listing`-environments) or would you then make use of the `newfloat`-package?

Comment: @LCsa I would simply use the `float` option for the selected environments.

Comment: @LCsa You're welcome! Glad I could help :-)

Comment: @LCsa I've updated my answer fixing the behaviour with the counters; you could be interested in this update.

Comment: You introduced the tmp-counter, do I see this correctly? I have to plough through the new code - I fear I'll have one or the other question...

Comment: @LCsa yes; to store the current value of the `lstlisting` counter, so as to restore the value once the other environments have redefined and used it.